# Converting enum to uint

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Why do I have to cast to uint when the enum is already an uint in the following example? Also does `: uint` even change anything? If I remove it, I get the same errors. `args.Progress` is an uint.

```
switch (args.Progress)
{
    case (uint) Values.value1: // works
        break;
    case Values.value2: // error
        break;
}

public enum Values : uint
{
    value1,
    value2
};
```

Comment: args.Progress is a uint presumably?

Comment: Well, you could as well cast args.Progress to a `Values` ;) `switch ((Values)args.Progress)`

Comment: @BenJackson yes, I added the info

Comment: @HenrikIlgen it's nice that there is another way so only one cast has to be done, but this doesn't answer why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The specification `: uint` does not make it an `uint`. It only defines the type of each member, but an `enum` is still an `enum`.

From an enum definition like:

```
public enum Foo : uint
{
    MemberA,
    MemberB
}
```

the compiler (more or less) creates a class with constants

```
public class Foo
{
    public const uint MemberA = 0;

    public const uint MemberB = 1;
 }
```

The reason to specify `: long` or anything is to make sure your values fit in there and that it maps correctly to whatever variables you try to cast it to. It is also important when working with `DllImport` of C code where it is mapped to constant values from the header files.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** `Values` and `uint` are **not the same**, but it's convertible explicitly.

`switch` requires both values (the value that is switched over and the values that it's compared against) to be of the same type (or at least to be implicitly convertible). You cannot implicitly convert an Enum value to the respective integral type (or vice-versa). For the same reason, you cannot assign an integral value to an Enum-type variable:

```
enum Foo { Spam = 1, Egg = 2, Bar = 4 }

Foo test = 1;
```

This causes a compile-time exception:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Foo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What you **can** do is cast either value to the other type:

```
Foo test = (Foo)1;
int test2 = (int)Foo.Egg;
```

The same goes for comparisons:

```
if(test == 1) { Console.WriteLine("It's 1!"); }
```

> error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Foo' and 'int'

```
if(test2 == Foo.Egg) { Console.WriteLine("It's an egg!"); }
```

> error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Foo'

However, cast one of the values to the type of the other, and it works like a charm:

```
if((int)test == 1) { Console.WriteLine("It's 1!"); }
if(test == (Foo)1) { Console.WriteLine("It's 1!"); }
if((Foo)test2 == Foo.Egg) { Console.WriteLine("It's an egg!"); }
if(test2 == (int)Foo.Egg) { Console.WriteLine("It's an egg!"); }
```

> It's 1!
>
> It's 1!
>
> It's an egg!
>
> It's an egg!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing explicit casting for every case, the cleaner way to fix your issue is doing explicit cast on your switch argument, which switch statement will propogate down to each case blocks as the following.

```
 switch ((uint) args.Progress) {
     case Values.value1: // works
         break;
     case Values.value2: // error
         break; }

 public enum Values : uint {
     value1,
     value2 };
```